# JQuery save via a form dragged and dropped items

Tags: jquery, forms, cart

I have used some code to be able to drag and drop items, this all works. What I need to is create a form so that I can save the selected items that have been added, what would be the best way to do this in a PHP mySQL site

(I am building a Joomla Component BTW)

```
       // jQuery Ui Droppable
    $(".basket").droppable({

        // The class that will be appended to the to-be-dropped-element (basket)
        activeClass:"active",

        // The class that will be appended once we are hovering the to-be-dropped-element (basket)
        hoverClass:"hover",

        // The acceptance of the item once it touches the to-be-dropped-element basket
        // For different values http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance
        tolerance:"touch",
        drop:function (event, ui) {

            var basket = $(this),
                    move = ui.draggable,
                    itemId = basket.find("ul li[data-id='" + move.attr("data-id") + "']");

            // To increase the value by +1 if the same item is already in the basket
            if (itemId.html() != null) {
                itemId.find("input").val(parseInt(itemId.find("input").val()) + 1);
            }
            else {
                // Add the dragged item to the basket
                addBasket(basket, move);

                // Updating the quantity by +1" rather than adding it to the basket
                move.find("input").val(parseInt(move.find("input").val()) + 1);
            }
        }
    });

    // This function runs onc ean item is added to the basket
    function addBasket(basket, move) {
        basket.find("ul").append('<li data-id="' + move.attr("data-id") + '">'
                + '<span class="name">' + move.find("h3").html() + '</span>'
                + '<input class="count" value="1" type="text">'
                + '<button class="delete">&#10005;</button>');
    }


    // The function that is triggered once delete button is pressed
    $(".basket ul li button.delete").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to save dynamically.. without a page refresh? If so, I would create a JSON object and use `$.post()` to post it to a PHP page that will handle the posted data.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ has some examples of the post...

Comment: I don't mind a page refresh, just look for the easiest implimentation

Comment: save what? Explanation of UI is pretty vague. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but assuming you just want to save the moved ID according to the session, you can create a server-side script that you can post the ID to save to:

```
function addBasket(basket, move) {
   //existing code snipped
   $.post('/addbasket/', {id: move.data('id')}).done(function () {
      console.log('Basket item saved');
   });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear I would like to be able to save all the items dragged to the cart into the database. Here is the source of the code http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/drag-n-drop-shopping-cart-with-jquery-ui-tutorial

Comment: I now know that the info is now being passed correctly because I can see it in my log, how do I create a page to capture the info and save in the DB